# How can I get Json.NET to convert Int32 to a URI

Tags: c#, json.net

In C# code I'd like to use my Int32 properties as they are designed - as int, but when converted to Json using Json.NET I'd like them to be serialized as a URI, so I don't have to map all my models to another model simply for json output. e.g. a simpliflied model:

```
public class Order
{
    public int? AccountID { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like this to be rendered like this:

```
{ "accountUri": "/account/123", "productUri": "/product/456", "total": 789.01 }
```

Note the casing and property renames have changed.

If AccountID is null then the json must render like this:

```
{ "productUri": "/product/456", "total": 789.01 }
```

In C# code I'd still like to use the properties as you would a normal int - so I'm thinking to use int operator overrides.

I don't want to use attributes on the model properties, but I'm happy to use a wrapper class for the Int32 and don't mind using attributes on the wrapper class if required.

The following code is a fair way from the answer, but you get the gist:

```
    public class Order
    {
        public AccountIdentifier AccountID { get; set; }
        public ProductIdentifier ProductID { get; set; }
        public decimal Total { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class IdentifierBase
    {
        private readonly string _uriPrefix;
        private int? _value;

        protected IdentifierBase(string uriPrefix, int? value)
        {
            _uriPrefix = uriPrefix;
            _value = value;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            if (_value.HasValue)
                return _uriPrefix + _value.Value;
            return null;
        }

        // insert int operator overrides here.
    }

    public class AccountIdentifier : IdentifierBase
    {
        public AccountIdentifier(int? value)
            : base("/account/", value)
        {
        }
    }

    public class ProductIdentifier : IdentifierBase
    {
        public ProductIdentifier(int? value)
            : base("/product/", value)
        {
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void JsonConvert()
    {
        var order = new Order
        {
            AccountID = new AccountIdentifier(123),
            ProductID = new ProductIdentifier(456),
            Total = 789.01M
        };

        using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            var writer = new JsonTextWriter(stringWriter) {Formatting = Formatting.None};
            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
            var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(settings);

            // Camel case the properties.
            serializer.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

            serializer.Serialize(writer, order);
            writer.Flush();
            var json = stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            Console.Write(json);
        }
    }
```

This outputs:

```
{"accountID":{},"productID":{},"total":789.01}
```

Three questions:

1. How do I rename "accountID" to "accountUri" (and "productID" to "productUri")?
2. How do I render the values of these properties (replace "{}" with the wrapper class's ToString() result?
3. How do I remove a property altogether when it's null?

Thanks.

**EDIT**: Even though it's quite a lot of work to write a converter for each model it does save writing two mappers.  Here's my proof of concept tests:

```
    [TestFixture]
    public class MyPoC
    {
        public class OrderJsonConverter : JsonConverter
        {
            public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
            {
                writer.WriteStartObject();

                var order = value as Order;

                if (order.AccountID.HasValue)
                {
                    writer.WritePropertyName("accountUri");
                    serializer.Serialize(writer, "/account/" + order.AccountID);
                }

                writer.WritePropertyName("productUri");
                serializer.Serialize(writer, "/product/" + order.ProductID);

                writer.WritePropertyName("total");
                serializer.Serialize(writer, order.Total);

                writer.WriteEndObject();
            }

            public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
            {
                var order = new Order();

                var jsonObject = JObject.Load(reader);
                order.AccountID = jsonObject.GetNullableIntFromUri("accountUri");
                order.ProductID = jsonObject.GetIntFromUri("productUri");
                order.Total = jsonObject["total"].Value<decimal>();
                return order;
            }

            public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
            {
                return typeof(Order).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
            }
        }

        [Test]
        public void JsonConvert_Is_Successful()
        {
            var order = new Order
            {
                AccountID = 123,
                ProductID = 456,
                Total = 789.01M
            };

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(order, Formatting.None, new OrderJsonConverter());
            Console.WriteLine(json);

            var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Order>(json, new OrderJsonConverter());
            Console.WriteLine("AccountID: {0}", deserialized.AccountID);
            Console.WriteLine("ProductID: {0}", deserialized.ProductID);
            Console.WriteLine("Total: {0}", deserialized.Total);
        }
    }
}

public static class JObjectExtensions
{
    public static int GetIntFromUri(this JObject jsonObject, string propertyName)
    {
        var id = jsonObject.GetNullableIntFromUri(propertyName);
        return id.Value;
    }

    public static int? GetNullableIntFromUri(this JObject jsonObject, string propertyName)
    {
        var uri = jsonObject[propertyName].ToObject<string>();
        var s = Regex.Replace(uri, @".*/(\d+)$", "$1");
        int id;
        if (int.TryParse(s, out id))
        {
            return id;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
{"accountUri":"/account/123","productUri":"/product/456","total":789.01}
AccountID: 123
ProductID: 456
Total: 789.01
```

Additional work would be to validate the uri is correct and not just a generic "rip the id from the end of the uri".

Comment: The proper solution here is to use the adapter pattern. Though it's not technically mapping, I suspect you won't like this because of your statement "so I don't have to map all my models to another model simply for json output". You should also look up separation of concerns. Honestly, you should really reconsider your position on potential solutions. You are going down a path that doesn't make much sense and is hard (and will be confusing to other developers). You would've been finished already using adapter pattern instead of waiting on an answer on SO.

Comment: Yes, I need to separate my concerns... I'll look at using the adaptor pattern instead. Thanks.

Comment: I've added an answer to give you a concise example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've decided to consider using the adapter pattern, here is a sample implementation with tests:

```
[TestFixture]
public class When_serializing_Order
{
    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
        };
    }

    [TestCase(123, 456, 789.01, "{\"accountUri\":\"/account/123\",\"productUri\":\"/product/456\",\"total\":789.01}")]
    [TestCase(null, 456, 789.01, "{\"productUri\":\"/product/456\",\"total\":789.01}")]
    public void Should_render_exact_json(int? accountId, int productId, decimal total, string expectedJson)
    {
        var order = new Order
        {
            AccountID = accountId,
            ProductID = productId,
            Total = total
        };
        string jsonOrder = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new OrderAdapter(order));
        Assert.That(jsonOrder, Is.EqualTo(expectedJson));
    }
}

public class Order
{
    public int? AccountID { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
}

public class OrderAdapter
{
    private readonly Uri _accountUri;
    private readonly Uri _productUri;
    private readonly decimal _total;

    public OrderAdapter(Order order)
    {
        _accountUri = order.AccountID != null ? CreateRelativeUri("account", order.AccountID.Value) : null;
        _productUri = CreateRelativeUri("product", order.ProductID);
        _total = order.Total;
    }

    public Uri AccountUri { get { return _accountUri; } }
    public Uri ProductUri { get { return _productUri; } }
    public decimal Total { get { return _total; } }

    private Uri CreateRelativeUri(string resourceType, int id)
    {
        return new Uri(String.Format("/{0}/{1}", resourceType, id), UriKind.Relative);
    }
}
```

If you have any questions, please post them with comments and I'll annotate anything that needs further explanation.

Comment: Great solution. Meets all my requirements... esp no attributes. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

1) Use the JsonProperty attribute's PropertyName parameter, such as:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "accountUri")]
public AccountIdentifier AccountID { get; set; }
```

2) The {} is the contents of the AccountIdentifier and ProductIdentifier classes. You will need to write a custom Json Converter for the Order class in order to customize the (de)serialization contents.

Here's the relevant [JSON.NET documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/CustomJsonConverter.htm).

3) You can also set this via the JsonProperty.

```
[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
```

**EDIT:** Here is part of a custom JsonConvert for the Order class. It doesn't use the attributes mentioned above, instead handling it manually. If someone else can provide a better (and more complete) solution please do.

```
public class OrderJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartObject();

        var obj = value as Order;

        writer.WritePropertyName("accountUri");
        serializer.Serialize(writer, obj.AccountID.ToString());

        writer.WritePropertyName("productUri");
        serializer.Serialize(writer, obj.ProductID.ToString());

        writer.WritePropertyName("Total");
        serializer.Serialize(writer, obj.Total);

        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(Order).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your edit is a good answer thanks! A lot of work to write all the overrides, but is more acceptable than your first answer as I don't want to use attributes. Thanks!